# Angular 2 RC6 testing: TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-testing

After a couple of hours of searching for the solution, I'm still getting the following error while testing my angular2 application:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null
        at TestBed._createCompilerAndModule (webpack:///~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:247:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:66075:44)
        at TestBed._initIfNeeded (webpack:///~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:213:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:66041:39)
        at TestBed.execute (webpack:///~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:275:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:66103:14)
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:367:28 <- config/spec-bundle.js:66195:45)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55179:29)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:106:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:54712:44)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:331:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55178:35)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:225:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55072:44)
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:123:28 <- config/spec-bundle.js:54391:51)
        at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:151:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:54419:43)
        at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:151:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:54419:43)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55212:38)
        at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55112:48)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:497:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55344:36)
        at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:437:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55284:26)
```

here is my test file:

```
describe('Widget service', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        BaseRequestOptions,
        MockBackend,
        {
          provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
          return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
        }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        {provide: WidgetService, useClass: WidgetService}
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should retrieve widgets by id',
    inject([WidgetService, MockBackend], fakeAsync((widgetService: WidgetService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
      let res: Response;
      mockBackend.connections.subscribe(c => {
        expect(c.request.url).toBe('src/app/assets/widget_00000011.json');
        let response = new ResponseOptions({body: '[{"id": "00000011", "displayName":"My NevisReports Server"}]'});
        c.mockRespond(new Response(response));
      });
      widgetService.getWidgetById('00000011').subscribe((response) => {
        res = response;
      });
      expect(res[0].id).toBe('00000011');
    }))
  );

});
```

My service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class WidgetService {

  widgets: any[];
  baseURL: string = 'http://localhost:8080/patterns/';
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getWidgetById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`/app/assets/widget_${id}.json`)
      .map(
        (res:Response) =>
          res.json()
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

I'm also using webpack where I call the initTestEnvironment.

Comment: The only thing wrong I see with the code is that you are forgetting to call `tick()` after you subscribe. I don't think this will cause the error you are getting. This would only cause the test to fail. Everything else looks good though. Is this the only test where you are getting this error?

Comment: Yes, the other tests pass.